# Simulating a click every half an hour

Tags: javascript, timer, click

I'm trying to write a program that would click a button every, say, 30 minutes. How would I write such a thing?

For example, if I went to google.com and clicked "Gmail" every 30 minutes.

Thanks!

Comment: Build a robot that can use a computer mouse and can tell time.

Comment: What you are looking for is a browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an automation tool. Selenium IDE can be setup to do this. http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterval` function to do that. setInterval takes two parameters first parameter is the code to be executed and the second parameter is represent the time interval that the code will be executed in miliseconds. Here an example:

```
 setInterval(click_button,30000);
  function click_button(){
   $("#button").click();//that select the buttons and clicks 
   }
```